# Is selected option selected if attribute is in DOM or not

Tags: javascript, html, css

[To create a Dual Listbox like Bootstraps](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) I needed to remove the default gray color of `selected` option. The only way to remove this gray color was to change the selected state of the element to false. No other trick worked to remove the gray background color of selected option.

Now if I do so, the attribute `selected` still remains in DOM but seems to be false. I thought if we have an element like:

```
<option value="1" selected>1: Lorem ipsum</option>
```

if `selected` is there it means always option selected true as it is the same as:

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">1: Lorem ipsum</option>
```

or

```
<option value="1" selected="true">1: Lorem ipsum</option>
```

but this seems not to be like so. Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

I've created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/npm6tn0m/ trying to demonstrate the scenario. Where the css

```
option[selected] {
   background-color: orange;
}
```

only works for the `selected` option which is set to false but still has the `selected` attribute in DOM. Cause this may vary across different browsers here is an image from what I see in OSX Chrome browser:

[image]

All code like in the fiddle also here on SO:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.special option');
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].selected = false;
}

setTimeout(function(){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('option');
 for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     console.log('Value = ' + elements[i].value + ' selected: '+ elements[i].selected);
 }
}, 1000);
```

```css
option[selected] {
   background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<select class="special" multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>1: Lorem ipsum</option>
  <option value="2"  >2: dolor sit amet</option>
</select>

<select multiple>
  <option value="3"  selected>3: Lorem ipsum</option>
  <option value="4"  >4: dolor sit amet</option>
</select>
```

Comment: One thing you can do is to add a class to the selected options on change of the select box. This way thing will be more in sync and you will have a better idea about what is selected and what is not.

Comment: to unset the selected option, you can set `document.querySelector('.special').selectedIndex=-1;` - also, the css you want is `option:checked` - inspecting the element shows that this is so, except the background color does not seem to want to change

Comment: Note: `elements[i].selected = false` is not the correct way. You should use `setAttribute` or `removeAttribute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought if we have an element like:
>
> ```
> <option value="1" selected>1: Lorem ipsum</option>
> ```
>
> if selected is there it means always option selected true as it is the same as:
>
> ```
> <option value="1" selected="selected">1: Lorem ipsum</option>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> but this seems not to be like so. Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

You're correct about how [boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) work, just not about what the `selected` boolean attribute represents. :-)

The [`selected` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected) represents the **default** selected state, not the *current* selected state. It's like an `input`'s `value` attribute in that way; the default (used in case of form reset, for instance), not the current value.

Just as the current value of an `input` is not represented in the DOM, similarly the current value of a `option`'s selectedness is not represented in the DOM.

Comment: As usual, after re-reading the answer a few times, now it is so clear and makes so much sense :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Different browser may treat this attribute differently. According to the MSDN documentation (for Internet Explorer):

> To select an item in HTML, it is not
>   necessary to set the value of the
>   SELECTED attribute to true. The mere
>   presence of the SELECTED attribute set
>   its value to true.

In firefox and Safari this does work:

```
<option selected='false' />
```

From what I can tell by looking at the official WC3 standard for HTML5, the supported case is only:

```
<option selected='selected' />
```

You will either need to selectively emit the attribute, or use `selected='false'` or use javascript to control which item is initially selected.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. You might also have a look at TJs answer as it really does answer what I thought is strange ...